# ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I was reading << Black Hat Python >> and trying the first bhnet.py program.

On one terminal, I run script

```
./bhnet.py -l -p 9999 -c
```

And on another terminal, run script

```
./bhnet.py -t localhost -p 9999
```

then type

```
<ctrl-D>
```

or

```
ls -alt
<ctrl-D>
```

The first terminal would return

```
File "bhnet.py", line 186, in client_handler
cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Below are the codes for the program

```
def client_handler(client_socket):
    global upload
    global execute
    global command

    # check for upload
    if len(upload_destination):

        # read all the buffer and write to destination
        file_buffer = ""

        # keep reading til none is available
        while True:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)

            if not data:
                break
            else:
                file_buffer += data

        # take the bytes and write them out
        try:
            file_descriptor = open(upload_destination,'wb')
            file_descriptor.write(file_buffer)
            file_descriptor.close()

            # acknowledge that file being wrote out
            client_socket.send(f"Successfully save file to {upload_destination}.\r \n")
        except:
            client_socket.send(f"Failed to save file to {upload_destination}.\r \n")

    # check for command execution
    if command:

        while True:
            #pop up a window
            client_socket.send(b"<BHP:#> ")

            # keep receiving data until \n
            cmd_buffer = ""
            while "\n" not in cmd_buffer:
                cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            response = run_command(cmd_buffer)
            client_socket.send(response)
```

I googled and even tried to upgrade openssl and none of these work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to be certain since you don't provide the client side code. However, I'm fairly confident this is happening:

When you type Ctrl-D, you're giving an end of file to the client's input. That is causing the client to `close` the socket it had previously connected to the server. Doing this causes the client's operating system to send a TCP `FIN` packet to the server. The `FIN` only tells the server that the client is finished *sending* data; there is no way in the normal TCP session termination of telling a peer that the peer may not send any more data.

But then the server *is* trying to `send` to the client, after the client has closed its socket.  When you try to send further data on a closed socket, *then* the destination peer's operating system sends a TCP `RST` packet. That isn't actually reported to the server on the `send` because the `send` function call is complete when the data is copied into the kernel -- whereas the `RST` is probably received by the kernel a few milliseconds later after it actually sent a data packet to the peer.

Hence that condition will be reported on the next operation on the socket which, here, is `recv`. Hence your program gets back an `ECONNRESET` error, which python translates into `ConnectionResetError` exception.

In other words:

```
Client            Server
------            ------
close()
        FIN =>    <OS receives FIN>
                  send(data)
        <= "data"
        RST =>
                  recv
                  <ECONNRESET>
```

One more thing: Depending on the exact timing, it's possible that your first call to `recv` in that loop is actually getting an end-of-file indicator (i.e. zero bytes). However, you're not checking for that, you just keep calling `recv` as long as there is no newline in the buffer. You really should be checking whether you got a zero byte string back from `recv` and terminate your loop in that case.

Once you've gotten the end-of-file indicator on the socket, you'll *never* get a newline added to the buffer. If the client had actually managed to receive the data you sent it *before* it closed the socket, then no `RST` would have been sent. In that case, your `recv` loop would run potentially forever, getting back zero bytes continuously but never finding the newline.